# No cradle found for filename.hs. Proceeding with implicit cradle

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, cradle

I am using haskell at VSCode. And i use stack's ghc.
(i wrote `export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.8.3/bin` at ~/.bashrc)

I don't have any problem at this, but nowadays, i can get the message at the VSCcode like this:

`No [cradle](https://github.com/mpickering/hie-bios#hie-bios) found for filename.hs. Proceeding with [implicit cradle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/implicit-hie)`

I cannot find the same message or solutions at Google. How can i solve this? or what cause the problem?

Comment: Not an answer, but this is produced by GHCIDE or perhaps haskell-lanuage-server which is commonly added in vscode via a plugin.

Comment: This seems to be a new issue with VSCode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have 2 files `./app/Main.hs` and `./test/Spec.hs`, you can create a `hie.yaml` at the workspace root `.` with:

```yaml
cradle:
  multi:
    - path: "./"
      config:
        cradle:
          stack:
            - path: "./app/Main.hs"
            - path: "./test/Spec.hs"
```

This should silence the error. Also, having `stack` in the system path is enough.

Comment: Having `stack` on `PATH` was not enough for me on Windows. A minimal `hie.yaml` (see the other answers) was.

Answer (score 14):

you can try create file "hie.yaml" to your project and write in "hie.yaml":
cradle:
stack:

Answer (score 12):

Bob and Maksim are right. For completeness sake I would add that I found https://github.com/mpickering/hie-bios to be of interest, and that a minimal `hie.yaml` containing

```
cradle:
  stack:
```

can work for a simple project.